# I thought cross-subdomain AJAX requests were allowed, but this Chrome error seems to indicate otherwise

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I know that cross-domain requests are disallowed for security reasons, but I was under the impression that only the top-level domain needed to match, that different sub-domains were okay.  However, I am getting this error from Chrome 7:

"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://foo.somedomain.com/dir/page.html from frame with URL http://bar.somedomain.com/otherdir/otherpage.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match"

What exactly are the rules for these types of requests?

Comment: I wasn't pointing my finger to chrome, I was just pointing out that it was chrome who was giving me this informative answer that actually questioned my understanding of the rules :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In short, the rules of the same origin policy are:

- same host
- same port
- same protocol

In your example you are violating the host rule, as a different subdomain could point to a different host/ IP than another, even if the second level domain is the same.

If you have no other possibility, you could try to use JSONP in your ajax request; this doesn't have an SOP.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Answer (score 5):

No cross sub domain requests are not allowed in any browser. But there are some ways like [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), using `iframes`, setting `document.domain` to make it work (although with some limitations).