# jQuery Ajax get error No Transport with a status 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing a jquery.ajax() call on one of our pages to fetch a small text file. I see some of the requests (not all) fail with resp.statusText: "No Transport" and resp.status : 0

What does the error mean (No Transport with a resp code of 0). Strangely it works on some browsers, and doesn't work on some. I couldn't find a patter by looking at the user agents of browsers, where it failed.

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am a beginner to javascript and jquery library, let me know if I omitted crucial information.

```
My use case:
abc.mydomain.com contains jquery.ajax(url:xyz.mydomain.com) call
```

Comment: Take a look at this post.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error)

Comment: @user199801 Please follow up on your question and tell us if you have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it prevents you from firing a request because it things you are trying to access another domain.  xyz.mydomain.com !==  mydomain.com.

Why that is not allowed?
Read

- [Use a Web Proxy for Cross-Domain XMLHttpRequest Calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)
- [Why the cross-domain Ajax is a security concern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466737/why-the-cross-domain-ajax-is-a-security-concern)

An example to why this is a security issue, assume you installed a bad plugin to your browser. If that plugin got the permission, it can read all loaded files to your browser and be able to edit/change/inject content and codes. Then it might send all collected data to designer own server.

*... The most common business needs that are easily accomplished with browser plug-ins are: modify default search, add side frames, inject new content into existing webpage ...*[more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w)

A good practice is to fetch the data thru ajax via JSON, if you are trying to access another site beside the one the script is calling from, then use JSON-P.

Read

- [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP)
- [JSON-P call to subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106178/get-json-from-subdomains-with-jquery)
- [Chrome ajax call to subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025061/i-thought-cross-subdomain-ajax-requests-were-allowed-but-this-chrome-error-seem)

  A common architecture is to call the current domain that the script is loaded from, then use server script to fetch data from the other domain where the other domain will response to the request and return the data.

A code snippets of your function will help us understand your issue more.