# Set document.domain back to its original value in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

Having a bit of trouble with document.domain - I can set it to the base domain but cannot set back to its original value (subdomain + domain) in FireFox or Edge, though it does work in Opera.

I have read a lot of documentation and doesn't seem to be mention of this limitation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the single origin policy protection. A subdomain can be changed to its parent domain, but not back again, because different subdomains can point to different hosts.

[I thought cross-subdomain AJAX requests were allowed, but this Chrome error seems to indicate otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025061/i-thought-cross-subdomain-ajax-requests-were-allowed-but-this-chrome-error-seem)

Comment: Dammit, 'a feature'.. Guess I best find a different way to do this then lol. Thanks @Daniel